# PHP SELF is automatically called on page load

Tags: php, html, file, server

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $fn=$_POST["filename"];
        $content=$_POST["txt"];
        $fp= fopen("abc.txt", "w") or die("unable to open file");
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" id="show">
        <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File Name"><br>
        <textarea name="txt" id="txtarea" id="txtarea" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="Text goes here..."></textarea><br>
        <input id="ixtbtn" type="submit" id="tabuttton" value="Done">
    </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Php is automatically getting called on page load. But I need it to be called when submit button is pressed.

Comment: Give submit button a name attribute and use it in your condition.

Comment: How to check it in condition?

Comment: For `<input id="ixtbtn" type="submit"  name="Submit" id="tabuttton" value="Done">` Check `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { ... your code ... }`

Comment: did you notice from tag is not highlighted..I think there is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        $fn=$_POST["filename"];
        $content=$_POST["txt"];
        $fp= fopen("abc.txt", "w") or die("unable to open file");
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <?php echo "<form action='" . htmlspecialchars(#_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "' method='post' id='show'>"; ?>
        <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File Name"><br>
        <textarea name="txt" id="txtarea" id="txtarea" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="Text goes here..."></textarea><br>
        <input id="ixtbtn" type="submit" id="tabuttton" value="Done" name='submitted'>
    </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you notice from tag is not highlighted..I think there is something wrong?

Comment: That's because you are including php tags inside a string.. you need to modify your form line slightly to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Played with your code a bit and noticed two things: (1) your  statement is outside your php code block and in straight html. (2) On my system (Firefox or Safari on OSX) that meant that the php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] was never translated back to php, it was treated as text and the post command kept posting to the server looking for a URL starting with the php  If I use echo inside php to output your HTML, the variables ($_SERVER) are not substituted and go in as straight text. So I put your html into a string variable first to translate the variables and then echoed your html. Saved the file as an PHP file instead of as an html file and your code worked just fine. So, four net changes.

1. Move the closing php statement (?>) to the end of the file
2. copy the HTML into a php string

   ```
   $outputString = "";
   $outputString = $outputString.'<!DOCTYPE html>';
   $outputString = $outputString.'<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Files</title>';
   $outputString = $outputString.'</head><body><center>';
   $outputString = $outputString.'<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post" id="show">';
   $outputString = $outputString.'<input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File Name"><br>';
   $outputString = $outputString.'<textarea name="txt" id="txtarea" id="txtarea" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="Text goes here..."></textarea><br>';
   $outputString = $outputString.'<input id="ixtbtn" type="submit" id="tabuttton" name="myButton" value="Done">';
   $outputString = $outputString.'</form></center></body></html>';
   ```
3. Echo the string
4. Save as .php instead of .html